# How to Send PDF or a document to printer in native Rust?

Tags: rust

I currently use external binary (.exe) to do this : [http://www.columbia.edu/~em36/pdftoprinter.html](http://www.columbia.edu/%7Eem36/pdftoprinter.html)
I call it from my app with `std::process::Command` and supply the file's path into it.

```
    const PDF_TO_PRINTER: &str = "pdftoprinter";
    let output = Command::new(PDF_TO_PRINTER)
        .args([file_name, printer_target.as_str()])
        .output()
        .map_err(|_| AppErr::from(AppErrEnum::PrinterError))?;
```

The problem is I need to make this process faster. Is there any rust native way to send a document to a printer effectively ?

[The windows API solution here](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/any-rust-library-that-helps-with-printers-on-windows/67689) is confusing for me and if it was the only solution, is there any example available ?

Comment: So your suggestion is use another pdf reader, such as SumatraPDF or Acrobat ?

Comment: I try sumatra and it's faster than pdftoprinter. I can cut the print response time from 1s to 400ms. It's a great increase! It's acceptable for me, but still doesn't answer the question how to print natively in rust (via windows API or something else)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing windows printer code, especially for a PDF printer turns out to be a very tough job. Like, obscenely tough.

> You essentially have to write a PDF to XPS conversion, (no XPS format
> crates, it looks like, so a lot of manual XML nonsense, on top of
> dealing with translating all the PDF concepts) then do Windows COM
> programming to send that as a stream (a lot simpler with `windows-rs`
> package, but still a lot to learn).

I asked this on Rust-forum and as of today there's no native Rust package dealing with this. So I'll leave it at that.

The current solution I use is to call other executable to do this.
The fastest I tried so far is SumatraPDF. Below is my implementation of this:

```
   use std::process::Command;


   let file_name = "pdf_file_name.pdf";
   let printer_target = "your_printer_name";
   let output = Command::new("/path/to/sumatra.exe")
        .args([
            "-print-to",
            printer_target,
            "-print-settings",
            "noscale",
            file_name,
        ])
        .output()
        .map_err(|_| // handle your error here // ))?;
```

Source:

1. https://www.sumatrapdfreader.org/docs/Command-line-arguments
2. https://users.rust-lang.org/t/how-to-send-pdf-or-a-document-to-printer/74963